# Angular - error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular

In Angular-12 application, I have this JSON api GET Request response from the backend:

```
{
  "message": "Company Detail.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
     "countries": [
        {
            "name": "Spain",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "Italy",
            "id": 1
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

Then I have this component to display countries as select dropdown:

```
countries!: any[];

this.api.get('countries/list', this.headers).subscribe(data => {
  this.countries = data.results.countries
});
```

I got this error:

> error TS2339: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'Object'

results is highlighted in:

> this.countries = data.results.countries

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the data type of your `data` response in the component (**must**) and API service (**optional but recommended**) with `interface` or `class`.

---

### SOLUTION

> response.interface.ts

```js
export interface IResponse<T> {
  message: string;
  error: boolean;
  code: number;
  results: T;
}

export interface ICountries {
  countries: ICountry[];
}

export interface ICountry {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
```

> api.service.ts

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class ApiService {
  ...

  get(url: string, headers: HttpHeaders): Observable<any> {
    const requestOptions = {
      headers: headers
    };

    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + url, requestOptions); 
  }
}
```

> .component.ts

```
import { ICountries, IResponse } from './response.interface';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    this.api
      .get('countries/list', this.headers)
      .subscribe((data: IResponse<ICountries>) => {
        this.countries = data.results.countries;
      });
  }
}
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mese2x)

Comment: Thanks so much. Solved. Is it possible to give me a good link for interface and service. I like the way you did it. It looks good and easy. Nor complex. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome, mate. Good to see that my answer can help you.